# SwiftUI: Hide unit of Measurement

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is there any option to hide the unit when displaying a Measurement in SwiftUI?

(Alternative: Showing the unit in a different font size.)

```
struct MeasurementStyle: View {
var body: some View {
    let speed = Measurement(value: 50, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour)
    let style = Measurement<UnitSpeed>.FormatStyle(
        width: .abbreviated,
        numberFormatStyle: .number
    )
    Text("\(speed, format: style)")
}
```

// Display: "31 mph"

// Desired: "31"

Comment: “speed.value” gives you the number

Comment: But does speed.value give me the numnber in the local format (e.g. mph)?

Comment: You would have to convert it. The other option is to use a formatter and split the string

Comment: If you want the conversion, why do you want to hide the unit? Displaying a unit value without the actual unit can not only be confusing, but also misleading to your users.

Comment: My main issue is arround the font size: I would like to have the numnber in huge font and the unit in a tiny font.

Comment: @DJJazz The `value` is just a `Double`. You'd need to format it yourself like any other. I'm a bit surprised that there's no `none` variant in [`Formatter.UnitStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurementformatter/1642067-unitstyle)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the worst way, but it seems to work:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MeasurementUnit<T: Unit>: View {
    let unit: String
    
    init(measurement: Measurement<T>) {
        let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        measurementFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        self.unit = String(measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement).split(separator: " ")[1])
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(unit)
    }
}

struct MeasurementValue<T: Unit>: View {
    var value: String
    
    init(measurement: Measurement<T>, format: String) {
        let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        measurementFormatter.locale = Locale.current
        self.value = String(format: format, Double(measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement).split(separator: " ")[0])!)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
    }
}

struct MeasurementView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HStack {
            MeasurementValue<UnitSpeed>(measurement: Measurement<UnitSpeed>(value: 12, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour), format: "%.1f").font(.system(size: 100))
            MeasurementUnit<UnitSpeed>(measurement: Measurement<UnitSpeed>(value: 12, unit: UnitSpeed.kilometersPerHour))
        }
    }
}
```